# Consuming External Webservices data in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform

I have the following requirement that I plan to fulfill through Hadoop frameworks.

- I have 40% of data sitting in a SQL Server Database
- I have 20% of data available through a Web service
- I have the rest 40% available through another database.

The data from the three sources need to be joined together to make a fourth data set , that I need to send to a 2 systems - one through Webservice call , another thru direct database import.

To achieve the above feature, Im planning to use Hadoop platform that we already have. The database pulls and push can be managed through Sqoop. The transformation is managed through SQL queries written through Hive. All of this is orchestrated through Oozie workflow.

In the complete gamut of things, what I would like to get help on is -

a. Is it a good approach to directly invoke a Webservice to fetch the data from hadoop? Or should I not use hadoop at all , if it involves fetching data from external webservices? I dont believe as there are ways to make it work but I would like your views.

b. If this approach is good, how can I materialize this? One option is to provide a oozie action that can invoke the webservice and write the response to the HDFS location. Are there any other better options?

Comment: Is data available through the webservice always the same, or does it changes over the time?

Comment: The data from the webservice can change every time. Its a daily job that syncs to the target systems.

Answer (score 0):

Customize an InputFormat and record reader for the webservice, by this way, hadoop just regard it as normal input. What you have to do first is to find a good way to split input from webservice into small ones, because mapreduce would start as many tasks as you have inputsplits.

at the same time, there may already have jdbc inputformat for you DB

Comment: As I mentioned before, I dont want to process in MR job. I just want to make this data available in HDFS so that Hive can take the complete transformation forward. Would that make any difference or did I get it wrong?